# how to use an specific image icon in flutter local notification?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

the application's logo is **PNG**,so in android lollipop this icon convert to be a white square. so i need to use another image in **JPG** format for flutter local notification.
i have two questions:

**first:**

*where should i put this image?*

**second:**

*how could i access this image?*

**the code is :**

```
 const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
      AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new image with size 48x48. You can have it as png as well as long as there is transparency and image itself is white.

Let's call this file ic_notification.png

Navigate to your project root directory. You will find `android` directory. Expand it see following directory in nested order
app
src
main
res
mipmap

if you don't see mipmap folder or different versions of mipmap folder, like mipmap-xxxdpi or mipmap-hdpi etc, create mipmap folder there and put your icon file in that folder.

On flutter side, replace `AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');` with `AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_notification');` (without .png)

You should have different icon for app launcher and notification as they serve different purpose.